# Adding multiple custom markers on Google Maps API after returning back from backend

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to add multiple markers on Google Maps API after data gets returned successfully from backend SQL table. Here is the code.

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PublicMapNew.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebContent_ApplicatorAreas" %>



  <head runat="server">

    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 70%;
      }
    </style>







    <style type="text/css">
      #map_canvas {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
      }
      .contextmenu {
        visibility: hidden;
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #8888FF;
        z-index: 10;
        position: relative;
        width: 140px;
      }
      .contextmenu div {
        padding-left: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/bootstrap.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mapStyling.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebContent/css/publicMap.css" />
    <link href='css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='css/registerCrop.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/Javascript/map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/WebContent/Javascript/publicMapNew.js"></script>
    <!-- Website Font style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/landingPage.css" />
  </head>
  <script>
    $.get("header.html", function(data) {
      $("#header").replaceWith(data);
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var user = null;
    var serverval = null;
    var usrapparea = null;
    var usrcroploc = null;
     //window.onload = init_publicmap;
  </script>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
      <div>
        <!-- /.header  -->
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="wrapper" style="height: 677px; width: 1923px;">

          <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" />
          <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 677px;"></div>
        </div>



        <script>
          var map = ""

          function init_publicmap() {
            PageMethods.QueryProducers("All", "All", QueryProducers_Success, Fail);
          }

          function customfeature(lat, long, type) {
            this.type = type;
            this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
          }

          function QueryProducers_Success(val) {
            var featuresloc = JSON.parse(val[1]);
            for (var i = 0; i < featuresloc.length; i++) {
              var customfeatureloc = new customfeature();
              customfeatureloc.type = featuresloc[i].croptype;
              customfeatureloc.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(featuresloc[i].lat, featuresloc[i].long);
              addMarker(customfeatureloc, map);
            }
          }

          function Fail(val) {

          }

          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 12,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.5007041, -93.5080389),
              disableDefaultUI: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
              mapOptions);
            var customControlDiv = document.getElementById("choiceMenuCrop");
            var customSearch = document.getElementById("adv-search");
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER].push(customControlDiv);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(customSearch);
            init_publicmap();
            //createPolygons(map);
          }

          function addMarker(feature, map) {
            var iconBase = '/WebContent/Images/IconsBase/';
            var iconHoneyBees = {
              url: iconBase + "honeybeesicon.JPG", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconFruitNuts = {
              url: iconBase + "fruits&nuts.JPEG", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconForageGrass = {
              url: iconBase + "Forage_Grass.JPG", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconFieldCrops = {
              url: iconBase + "FieldCrops.png", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconNurseryGreen = {
              url: iconBase + "Nursery_Greenhouse.JPG", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconVegetable = {
              url: iconBase + "vegetable.png", // url
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var icons = {
              "Vegetables": {
                icon: iconVegetable
              },
              "Greenhouse and Nursery": {
                icon: iconNurseryGreen
              },
              "Field Crops": {
                icon: iconFieldCrops
              },
              "Fruits and Nuts": {
                icon: iconForageGrass
              },
              "Forage, Grassland": {
                icon: iconFruitNuts
              },
              "Honeybees": {
                icon: iconHoneyBees
              }
            };
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: feature.pos,
              icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
              map: map
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7FTNE22Wl6S6DTQF83sTZTqbFFPzEkmU&libraries=drawing,places,geometry&callback=initialize">
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

The main part to focus on is the QueryProducers_Success function because I have tested it ,it is returning data and adding successfully to the marker but it is not appearing on the map. Please help me.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone is having difficulty understanding the problem I can explain more in comments..!!

Comment: Could you please add minimal running example, which could helps to understand, where is the issue and what's not working.

Comment: I got the html part working i hope it helps Div...also i created this another post to help you get the gist of the problem..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569450/custom-google-marker-not-visible-on-google-map-api-v3?noredirect=1#comment68375479_40569450                                             Hope this helps you understand...please still let me know if anything is unclear..!!