# Custom Google Marker not visible on Google Map API V3

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to add multiple markers to place on Google Maps API according to the SQL data returned returned to me.The code works fine I debugged it and it is adding marker to map but it is not visible. It is not showing any error in Firebug nor at console of back-end (asp.net). Please help me out it frustrating me like crazy.

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.658354982307571, -96.396270512761134),
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  init_publicmap();



  var iconBase = '/WebContent/Images/IconsBase/';
  var iconHoneyBees = {
    url: iconBase + "honeybeesicon.JPG", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var iconFruitNuts = {
    url: iconBase + "fruits&nuts.JPEG", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var iconForageGrass = {
    url: iconBase + "Forage_Grass.JPG", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var iconFieldCrops = {
    url: iconBase + "FieldCrops.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var iconNurseryGreen = {
    url: iconBase + "Nursery_Greenhouse.JPG", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var iconVegetable = {
    url: iconBase + "vegetable.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
  };
  var icons = {
    "Vegetables": {
      icon: iconVegetable
    },
    "Greenhouse and Nursery": {
      icon: iconNurseryGreen
    },
    "Field Crops": {
      icon: iconFieldCrops
    },
    "Fruits and Nuts": {
      icon: iconForageGrass
    },
    "Forage, Grassland": {
      icon: iconFruitNuts
    },
    "Honeybees": {
      icon: iconHoneyBees
    }
  };

  function addMarker(feature) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: feature.pos,
      icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
      map: map
    });

    return marker;
  }

  //createPolygons(map);
  function init_publicmap() {
    PageMethods.QueryProducers("All", "All", QueryProducers_Success, Fail);
  }

  function customfeature(lat, long, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  }

  function QueryProducers_Success(val) {
    var featuresloc = JSON.parse(val[1]);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < featuresloc.length; i++) {
      var customfeatureloc = new customfeature();
      customfeatureloc.type = featuresloc[i].croptype;
      customfeatureloc.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(featuresloc[i].lat, featuresloc[i].long);
      var marker = addMarker(customfeatureloc, map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(featuresloc[i].cropname);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

  }

  function Fail(val) {

  }
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong..!!

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path? `var iconBase = 'http://yourwebsite.com/WebContent/Images/IconsBase/';` If you're using the relative path, make sure it's relative to the current page.

Comment: thanks for the comment risan..but i tried the marker icon with static data and it worked so the problem is not that the icons are not loading and also it would have shown on firebug but there is not a single error  their..:(